# Title appears as Dwg No in Solidworks Drawing

Tags: solidworks

When I add a part to a drawing in Solidworks, the title appears as the Dwg No in Solidworks Drawing. I am using the standard [ANSI landscape template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icaBt.png). Currently the Dwg No section has a randomly assigned number but if I add a part it would change to that part's name. How do you fix this issue so nothing appears in the Dwg No section, but the title appears until Title?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off-topic, and seems to belong on [Engineering SE](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solidworks).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.